# Can't create empty Jenkins Plugin project in NetBeans

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, jenkins, maven

I'm trying to write my first own Jenkins Plugin. I followed the instructions (using NetBeans as IDE) as describend [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-SettingUpEnvironment).

So I installed the NetBeans plugin for Jenkins/Stapler development and modified my settings.xml. When I do New Project » Maven » Jenkins Plugin I unfortunately get the following error

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:LATEST) -> [Help 1]

To get a more verbose output I added --debug and --errors to the Global Execution Options and got the following output:
[ConsoleOutput](https://pastebin.com/ckAPBc7g)

This line seems to be the root of the error, but I couldn't find any solution for it:

> Could not find metadata
>   org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local
>   (C:\Users\Username.m2\repository)